# IBM Bluemix Mobile Data Services, Loading data into the cloud

Tags: mobile, cloud, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I want to create an android application, I want my application data to be persistent. There is a file that I want to save every time to the Bluemix server.
I want to confirm the following, for a situation in which a user "A" from my application saves the data to the IBM Bluemix Server, and if there are more than 2000 users saving the same user-related file in the server:

- Will there be any differences between all the different user files?
- Will there be any collisions?
- Will I be able to differentiate the
  files of other users?
- Will I be able to save and retrieve the saved
  file of only that particular user?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Mobile Client Access (MCA)](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/mobile-client-access/) service you will be able to do exactly what you ask.

MCA can provide you with a unique identifier for each authenticated Facebook, Google+, or custom style user, enabling you to manage your data appropriately. I recommend the [Cloudant NoSQL DB](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cloudant-nosql-db/) service for fast and easy database management.

See the [MCA docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/index.html) and [Android sample](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-helloauthentication) for further information.